# Fpqc sheaf property of algebraic stacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

It is known that algebraic spaces are fpqc sheaves. A proof by Gabber can be found in the Stacks Project at [tag 0APL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0APL).

Naturally one may ask whether this generalizes to algebraic stacks. Given an algebraic stack $\mathcal X$, is it true in general that $\mathcal X$ is a stack in the fpqc topology?

Remark. Following the proof of Gabber one can show that if there exists a smooth ind-quasi-affine surjection from a disjoint union of affine schemes then the answer is true. However this seems to indicate that the answer may be false in general.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. When linking to the Stacks Project, it is best practice to link to the specific section or result you're referring to using the tag system. It's also a good idea to put things like the remark you made in the comments in to the main post with an [edit] so that more people see it. I've done both for you this time.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0GRH

Comment: So it seems that general algebraic stacks (without ind-quasi-affine diagonal) do not satisfy fpqc descent?